# I want to alert the values outside on the each function ,cuz i will put that variable in inside an ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to alert the values outside on the each function. Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" value="1" class="product_id"> 
<input type="text" value="2" class="product_id"> 
<input type="text" value="3" class="product_id"> 

$(document).on('click','.proceed_btn',function(){
    $('.product_id').each(function(){
        var q = $(this).val();
    });
    alert(q);
});
```

Comment: Put the values in an Array. Access it in AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) like in the following snippet:

```js
$(document).on('click','.proceed_btn',function(){ 
    var q = $('.product_id').map(function(index, item) {
      return item.value;
    }).toArray();
    console.log(q.join(', '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form>
  <input type="text" value="1" class="product_id"> 
  <input type="text" value="2" class="product_id"> 
  <input type="text" value="3" class="product_id">
  <button type="button" class="proceed_btn">proceed</button>
</form>
```

Comment: it work but if i press the button again the result will be "20 27 20 27"

Comment: Just declare the q var in click event. Or if the purpose is to send form data at server side so just use form.serialize() and send it.